# jboss configuration via ipv6 version jboss-eap-7.4

Tags: configuration, jboss, ipv6

Step 1: I made changes in standlone.xml

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:[::1}]"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
     <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:[::1]}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset6:0}">
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
     <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:8080}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="${jboss.mail.server.host:localhost}" port="${jboss.mail.server.port:25}"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

Step 2: Made changes in standalone.config

if [ "x$JAVA_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1303m -Xmx1303m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=false"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS -Djava.awt.headless=true"
else
echo "JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values: $JAVA_OPTS"
fi

Step 3: Made changes standalone.conf.bat

rem # Prefer IPv6
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=false -Djava.net.preferIPv6Stack=true"

when i start jboss with address Admin console listening on    http://[::1]:9990

able to run jboss
when i try to run jboss Admin console listening on http://[::1]:8080  address
its shwoing unable to redirect page

but in ipv4 when i try 8080 port its working its able redirect 9990 port number

so can anyone help me out via IPV6

i m expecting that
Admin console listening on http://[::1]:8080
for ipv6 machine jboss should run with ipv6 address
so 8080 port is listening its hsowing but not able to start jboss
i need Admin console listening on http://[::1]:8080 this address should work for jboss via ipv6 machine

the error i m getting

version   jboss-eap-7.4

http://[::1]:8080/noredirect.html

Unable to redirect.
An automatic redirect to the Administration Console is not currently available, this is most likely due to the administration console being exposed over a network interface different to the one you are connected to.

To access the Administration console you should contact the administrator responsible for this JBoss EAP installation and ask them to provide you with the correct address.